# Signal leakage when volume is turned all the way down

Tags: leakage-current, guitar-pedal

I was hoping I could get help with a design I have breadboarded/diagrammed with regards to a low level signal still present when I have my volume pot turned all the way down. When I turn my volume control down all the way there is a low volume/high treble sputtering distortion signal that's still audible. I thought is was a grounding issue on my volume pot but it's not coming from there, not exactly sure where it's coming from. I hope I tagged this correctly as I'm still learning proper terms.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have 2 wires from your power supply going into the same row on your breadboard.

Comment: @brhans where is that happening?

Comment: Left side of your pic. Black & Brown wires both plugged into the blue `-` row.

Comment: Ah, those two wires just ground my 1/4" TRS inputs

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce R11 to zero if you expect the volume to go to zero.

If you are hearing distortion, the output may be clipped. Since they put the volume control after the amp, this is a possibility. Do you have a scope?

I don't care for this design. LM386 are designed to drive speakers, so although they will work, they are not the best choice. The output impedance is variable, it depends on the volume setting.

Comment: When I take R11 away and go straight to ground I have the same issue. I do have a scope, but I'm just learning by doing at this point, just getting started, so I'm not sure how to fully use the tools. At what points should I check with the scope?

Comment: I don't see a ground connection to the bottom row on the breadboard.

Comment: it's off the edge of the photo at the very bottom of the board, there is one though.

Comment: What is your input?  Is the distortion present even if the input is shorted?  If yes, then look at the output of each stage and see where the unwanted signal exists.

Answer (score 0):

The contacts on many breadboards make poor connections.
Many cheap volume controls make a poor ground connection with the slider.